# How to know when databinding is *really* complete for a DataGridView?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm getting really rather frustrated with this DataGridView control. What I really want to do is simply to make sure the grid is initially sorted in some default way (though the user may sort it differently if so desired).

I tried assigning the DataSource and then invoking the Sort method. This sometimes works, but sometimes leads to an InvalidOperationException. Debugging it seems to indicate that the times it doesn't work the grid has no rows or columns. The intermittent nature of the behavior has me guessing there's a race going on, so perhaps the grid is not binding synchronously when I assign the data source, but rather does so in the background.

So I look at the MSDN doc and find there's an event DataBindingCompleted. That looks just about right, and I attach a handler. The event is declared on the grid itself, so you'd think it meant that all databinding for the whole control has finished. Yet it fires a *lot* of times (I don't know, but am guessing once per cell) for each time I actually bind new data to the grid.

I suppose I can live with this; the overhead is probably not huge as the grid is presumably smart enough not to do much at all if asked to sort itself "col1 asc" and it's already sorted that way. (If not, I could always do that test myself and not call sort unless I'm actually going to change something.) Still, I would really like to know if there really is no way to know when the databinding is truly complete.

Comment: It seems strange what you are describing. Can you please post the exact error message from the `InvalidOperationException` you are getting? Looking at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0868ft3z.aspx) shows only three well defined reasons for this exception. Please be sure to read the remarks of that page carefully, there is a lot of info there.

Answer (score 1):

We usually use the DataBound event when processing post-bound details such as sorting, and have used this for years without the behaviour describing. Perhaps this is the event you're looking for?